# Why is text disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a very simple chatbox. The text that I write in the form  is not seen on the chat area. Actually ,it is seen for a second and after from chatarea. How can I keep the  messages on the chat area ? (it works properly on the jsfiddle but not on my browsers)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitMsg").click(function() {
    var userMessages = $("#userMsg").val(); // stored content in the text box
    var prevMessage = $("#chatArea").html();
    $("#userMsg").val(""); // clear textbox
    $("#chatArea").html(prevMessage + "<br>" + userMessages);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: #ACD8F0;
  ;
  width: 604px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
}
#chatArea {
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
#userMsg {
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#submitMsg {
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <p class="Welcome">Welcome</p>
  </div>
  <div id="chatArea"></div>
  <form id="ChatInput">
    <textarea id="userMsg" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Enter your text here.." rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="SEND" id="submitMsg">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Learn to format your code.  It will dramatically improve your ability to troubleshoot.  As it is, the code is very difficult to analyze due to erratic indenting and spaces.

Comment: Also - if it works here, but not in your browser, I'm guessing that you have an issue with the form actually submitting, likely due to a javascript error that would appear in your developer console....

Comment: "please fix my working code" ... no. reproduce the problem. if it works when you isolate the coed then the problem is somewhere else and your isolated code is useless to anyone troubleshooting..

Comment: @cale_b is correct, use your console to troubleshoot first. Also if you're asking for help, format your code better and we don't need the .CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your submit button. Forms without an action specified default to a GET/POST request for the current page (thus reloading it). If you remove the 'type="submit" from `<input type="submit" name="Send" value="SEND" id="submitMsg">`, it should work. Alternatively, if you add `action="javascript:void(0);"` to your form tag, it should also solve the problem.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this perhaps? Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use the event object to prevent the default action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitMsg").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userMessages = $("#userMsg").val(); // stored content in the text box
    var prevMessage = $("#chatArea").html();
    $("#userMsg").val(""); // clear textbox
    $("#chatArea").html(prevMessage + "<br>" + userMessages);
  });
});
```